# User incorrectly getting logged in with invalid data, after having logged out previously

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, authentication, uistoryboardsegue

I have a login screen that ensures that there is valid data in the input fields before attempting to login. Or so I thought.

The problem is when we come back from another screen that "logouts" the user, if I submit with an invalid username password combo after returning to this page, I see the error dialog as expected, but after dismissing it I am then taken to the next view controller as if I logged in.

Any help please?

```
@IBAction func btnSubmit(sender: UIButton) {
        if txtUsername.text == "" || txtPassword.text == "" {
            //they're missing a username or password
            displayAlert("Missing Field(s)", message: "Please enter both a username and password")
        }else {
            //we check if they're in signup/login mode
            if Switch.on {
                //user is in signup mode
                if txtPassword.text != txtConfirmPassword.text {
                    //the password fields do not match
                    displayAlert("Mismatched Passwords", message: "Please enter matching passwords")
                }else {
                    //the password fields do match, and the user can register with this username/email and password
                    var user = PFUser()
                    user.username = txtUsername.text
                    user.password = txtPassword.text
                    // other fields can be set just like with PFObject

                    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if let error = error {
                            let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as! String
                            // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
                            self.displayAlert("Signup Error", message: errorString)
                        } else {
                            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("register", sender: self)
                        }
                    }                }
            }else {
                //user is in login mode and we can submit credentials


                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(txtUsername.text, password:txtPassword.text) {
                    (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if let error = error {
                        let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as! String
                        // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
                        self.displayAlert("Login Error", message: errorString)
                    } else {
                        if PFUser.currentUser()!.username != nil {
                            // Do stuff after successful login.
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my logout call from the other page

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "logout" {
            PFUser.logOut()

        }
    }
```

Comment: Debug with breakpoints and single stepping to find where the error is, inserting print() statements can also help. Debugging is a necessary skill to learn.

Comment: @zaph sorry, i'm very new to iOS development, and just development in general.

Comment: @zaph i added println statements to various locations and discovered that PFUser.currentUser().username property is equal to nil after logout from the other page.

Comment: however, after i have returned to the login view controller, when i hit submit, the segue occurs and the previous page where i just logged out from is displayed. and the the println command i put within the viewDidLoad method isn't firing

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is that you're not uses the succeeded Bool that is returned in the completion handler. When I log users in with Parse I use that primarily to see if log in was successful or not, if it is not successful I will then check what the error message was. This should stop you from allowing the user to continue into the app when they have not been logged in correctly.

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        let errorString = error!.userInfo?["error"] as! String
        // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
        self.displayAlert("Signup Error", message: errorString)
    } else {
        if succeeded {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("register", sender: self)
        } else {
            //Something went wrong
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some detail to your answer here.